# Moving Divs in JavaScript with key presses

Tags: javascript, html, location, move, keypress

I'm doing an HTML/JavaScript based game, the game objective is 2 monsters collecting cakes and avoid other thing than cakes. I've created 2 divs where each one is the zone where I want the characters to move around. First i'm starting with just the basic (Space key to Jump), but this is one of those games that if one character goes up, the other one comes down. For now, i'm testing the code to just one character to see if it works, if it does i'm planning to program to the other character do the opposite.
This is the code I got for the Key Presses:

```
function onKeyPressed(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        left = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        right = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38) {
        up = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
        down = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 32) {
    updateMonster1Place();
    updateMonster2Place();
    }
}

// function to be called when a key, in the keyboard, is released
function onKeyReleased(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        left = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        right = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38) {
        up = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
        down = false;
    }
}
```

And this is the first function called `updateMonster1Place();`

```
function updateMonster1Place() {

    if (monster1.top >= 500){
    for( var i=0; i = 100; i++){
    monster1.top = i + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code is wrong, because, my character is placed at `Top = 500px`, and what I want to happen, is to the character slide, and just stops when his `Top = 100`.

I hope you understand what im trying to do here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) possible for demo,would be more easy to solve the issue

Comment: I would recommend using Mousetrap (https://craig.is/killing/mice) for a keyboard based game as it can do some advance key binding combination .

Comment: If you want the character to slide, wouldn't you use ``left`` instead of ``top``?

Comment: Im trying to put on JSFiddle, but I don't understand how that website works yet. Give me some minutes. 

@dipole_moment I want them to slide top! D:

Comment: How can I import the files I have in my computer? Otherwise you can't see what I see. Anw, this is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/e9g0qmyd/ @divy3993